# How to solve a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python

CODE:

```
import csv 
import sys
def costo_camion(costo_camion):   #def es la palabra reservada
   suma = 0
   f = open('Data/camion.csv', 'rt')
   headers = next(f).split(',')
   for line in f:
       row = line.split(",")
       costo = float(row[2]) * int(row[1])
       suma = suma + costo  
   f.close()
   return(suma)
   
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    costo_camion = sys.argv[1]
else:
    costo_camion = 'Data/camion.csv'

suma = costo_camion('Data/camion.csv')
print('Costo Total', suma)
```

> Line
> else:
> costo_camion = 'Data/camion.csv')
> shows up the type error 'str' object is not callable (Python) and I don't know why, the code without this part:
> `if len(sys.argv) == 2 etc` works just fine
> thanks**

Comment: Can you tell me: what is `costo_camion` in your code? Is it a function or is it a string?

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting the variable `costo_camion` with either `sys.argv[1]`, or `Data/camion.csv`. This means instead of calling your function (also called `costo_camion`) you try to call your string. This makes no sense to Python, hence the error. Try naming the file location something like `costo_camion_file` instead to clear up the confusion.

Comment: Call different things different names.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Also, please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 3 in your code, you name your function `costo_camion`:

```py
...
def costo_camion(costo_camion):
...
```

Then, on either line 15 or 17 you initialize a variable also named `costo_camion`:

```py
...
costo_camion = sys.argv[1]
...
costo_camion = 'Data/camion.csv'
```

On line 19, you then try to call the function `costo_camion`:

```py
...
suma = costo_camion('Data/camion.csv')
...
```

This will give you an error, because by this point no such function exists -- you have overwritten that name by using it for your variable.

My suggestion: re-name the variable on lines 15 and 17 to something like `costo_camion_filepath`. After that, you should no longer get this error. (You might have other issues with this code, but this particular error should be gone. :) )